# InlineKeyboard using requests telegram library

Tags: python, telegram

I'm trying to insert the keyboard under the telegram posts with requests python library, but i receive this error: `name 'inline_keyboard' is not defined`. I'm following this documentation https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton

My code:

```
def SendMessage(chat_id, text, parse_mode, reply_markup):
    """
    :param chat_id integer or string
    :param text string max 4096 characters
    """

    response = requests.post(url="https://api.telegram.org/botMYTOKENXXX/sendMessage",
                             data={'chat_id': chat_id, 'text': text, 'parse_mode': 'Html', 'reply_markup': 'array_of_arrays'}).json()


keyboard = inline_keyboard[("text")]
SendMessage("myid", "text" , parse_mode="HTML", reply_markup = keyboard)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**inline_keyboard** is a dictionary key.You must enter it in the **string**.
Also convert a **dictionary** to **json** with the **json library**

```
import requests,json

token="YourToken"

def SendMessage(chat_id, text, parse_mode, reply_markup):
    data={'chat_id': chat_id, 'text': text, 'parse_mode': parse_mode, 'reply_markup': reply_markup}
    return requests.post(url="https://api.telegram.org/bot"+token+"/sendMessage",data=data).json()
    

keyboard = json.dumps({'inline_keyboard':[[{"text":"hello","callback_data":"clicked"}]]})

SendMessage("myid", "text" , parse_mode="HTML", reply_markup = keyboard)
```

Comment: Okay, i got it, thank's. I'm trying your code, but it said me: "must be str, not NoneType"

Comment: @JosephMart Check the data variable in the function.Is there a None value in the data variable?

Comment: Where? In def get_photo(soup) ?

Comment: @JosephMart No,In SendMessage

Comment: I don't know what to do, sorry :((

Comment: @JosephMart After defining the data variable in the SendMessage function, print its value

Comment: @JosephMart If you don't understand, upload your code somewhere.Until I check it out

Comment: Okay the problem was not your code (obv). If i want open an url by clicking keyboard, what i need to do? I tried this: keyboard = json.dumps({'inline_keyboard':[[{"text":"Offerta","callback_data":link_def}]]}) where link_def is url that i need to open

Comment: @JosephMart You should read the Telegram bot document.To do this, write **url** instead of **callback_data**

Comment: Perfect, all is working! Last thing, if i want add a second keyboard i need to do in this way? [{"text":"FIRSTKEY","callback_data":"clicked"}]:[{"text":"SECONDKEY","callback_data":"clicked"}] ?

Comment: @JosephMart Your code has a bit of a problem.In two examples the location of the buttons is different.Example1: `[[{"text":"FIRSTKEY","callback_data":"clicked"},{"text":"SECONDKEY","callback_data":"clicked"}]]` 
 Example2:`[[{"text":"FIRSTKEY","callback_data":"clicked"}],[{"text":"SECONDKEY","callback_data":"clicked"}]]`